# Receive javascript content using curl

Tags: javascript, curl

I have an page with javascript merged with html.  I need to dump the javascript.

Is there any way to do this with curl?

Sample:

```
 curl "10.0.0.1/index.php?search=aaa"
```

and I need the output with the javascript contents.

Comment: Huh? Can you please rephrase the question?

Comment: I re-phrased it for him :) I think he wants to dump the HTML with the Javascript Content, some javascript content is loaded in and won't be seen in the source of the page.

Comment: No javascript is displayed

Comment: run curl -sL google.com and view the source of page in browser

Answer (score -1):

Jack, If I'm understanding you correctly. You will need to use PhanthomJS or Selenium to get the full rendered version of the entire page with all the Javascript content as presented in a browser.

With curl you're going to just get the raw html, which is not what you're looking for.

Comment: i'm look for an simple linux cli tool like curl or wget

Comment: I did extensive research on this and the only way I was able to do it was with the above mentioned tools.